# Long running tasks in message-driven beans and timeouts

Tags: java, ejb, jms, message-driven-bean, apache-tomee

I want to process some very long running tasks using MDBs (hours), but MDBs are backed by JMS, which has some timeout (about 10 minutes in tomEE I think).

To make things worse, jobs are persistent too.

Since I can't catch the timeout exception on the MDB (can I?), I was considering the option of manually deal with the JMS consumer. Manually dealing with it can be done in two ways: synchronously or asynchronously.

Asynchronously I'll fall back to a stateless bean that implements MessageListener, and then I'll just not be able to treat the timeout again.

Synchronously, I guess, I can deal with the timeout in the catch block, but then, how can I implement a pool of instances/workers/whatever inside TomEE+ that are listening to a queue, waiting for a job to process? (remember, timeout here is not the time to wait for a message to appear in the queue, but the time to execute the long running task)

Comment: Why don't you fork off the long running process to a separate object ?

Comment: If there's a way to control the pool size of these separate objects, it could be a way. Do you want to try an answer? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you fork off the long running process to a separate object ? 
>
If there's a way to control the pool size of these separate objects, it could be a way. Do you want to try an answer? :-)

You do not want an uncontrolled object growth over time ? Hmmm...I can see where you are going with that.

The only thing I can think of is use a FixedThreadPool from the concurrent framework. Spawn a thread for executing the long running task and ensure that the MDB returns immediately after handing over the work. Keep the thread pools controlled by profiling your application in a test environment.

Application servers like Weblogic and Websphere give you sophisticated frameworks like WorkManager for such tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to separate consuming JMS message and long running processing tasks

MDB could get message from queue and call stateless session bean with 
[Asynchronous Method Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)

Comment: if I create a new transaction in the SLSB, will I get rid of the MDB timeout?

Comment: AFAIK No. The MDB will return only when the SLSB finishes.

Comment: @ramp - Hmm. Async call create new transaction.  From EJB 3.1 spec.

4.5.3 Transactions

Client transaction context does not propagate with an asynchronous method invocation. From the Bean Developer’s view, there is never a transaction context flowing in from the client. This means, for example, that the semantics of the REQUIRED transaction attribute on an asynchronous method are exactly the same as REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: @user3145155 - you are correct. I was responding to the OP's question about SLSB and missed the Asynchronous Method Invocation part in your answer. Essentially this then is the same solution I have outlined too in my answer. This comes off the shelf with EJB 3.1. I have edited my answer to remove the remark about the feasibility of this solution and also upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [ManagedExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) exists in JEE7 to handle the execution of asynchronous tasks.  By leveraging a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface implementation (see [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)) a task can be made cancellable as well.  The following is meant to be an example, don't copy it 1:1 and use it in production.  It has a memory leak in the map of future's by UUID is never cleaned up.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class AsyncTaskManager {

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService mes;

    private Map<String, Future> futureByUUID = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    /**
     * Launch the provided Future implemented task.
     * @param runnable The runnable implementation to execute.
     * @param <R> The type of the task result returned.
     * @return The UUID that the executing ask is mapped to.
     */
    public <R> String launch (RunnableFuture<R> runnable) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        mes.submit(runnable);
        futureByUUID.put(uuid, runnable);
        return uuid;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a future instance by it's UUID.
     * @param uuid The uuid of the future.
     * @param <T> The type of the future's result.
     * @return The future instance.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Future<T> getByUUID (String uuid) {
        return (Future<T>)futureByUUID.get(uuid);
    }
}
```

There are a whole set of interfaces and classes that can be combined to change the behavior of your task within the executor service.  For example the [ManagedTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedTask.html) interface provides access to some of these behaviors.

The ManagedExecutorService is leveraged for the `@Asynchronous` EJB method annotation as mentioned in the answer by MGolovanov.  The task creation and Future instance creation is handled by the EJB framework.